# How to Start UITableView on the Last Cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

In Apple's Messages app, when you click a correspondent's name and switch to the table view of the conversation (with balloons for each message), the table appears scrolled all the way to the end. No animation or anything, it's just there.

Similarly, in Tweetie 2, when you load the tweets view, it appears right where you last looked at it. No animation to get there, it's just there, as if none of the cells above were loaded.

How do these apps do this? Are they calling `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` somewhere in the table controller? If so, how do they know what to pass to `atScrollPosition:`? And in what method is it called?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`scrollToRowAtIndexPath` should work.

In `viewWillAppear:`, try this:

```
[theTableView reloadData];    
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumberHere inSection:sectionNumberHere];
[theTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

`rowNumberHere` is the row number in the data source you want to scroll to.

`atScrollPosition` is just one of the values in the `UITableViewScrollPosition` enum which can determine where on the screen the row number you want will show up. However, depending on the number of rows and which row you are scrolling to, it may not make a difference.

Putting `reloadData:` avoids an exception if the data is not loaded yet in `viewWillAppear:`.  If you put the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in `viewDidAppear:`, you would not need the `reloadData:` but you will see the table jump a little which you say you don't want.

Edit:
@Theory, try changing your code as follows...

```
[tableView reloadData];
int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Please note `numberOfRowsInSection` returns row count, not the last row number (which is row count - 1).

Comment: Thanks, this appears to be exactly what I needed to know, except that my implementation crashes the app. :-( See my "answer" below.

Comment: D’oh! Of course, I missed that I wanted the cell index number not the row number. Thanks! I'll update my own answer to show my specific solution.

Comment: Your note about depending on row count and row position sometimes it may not make a difference. Please help on what can be done in such scenario.

Comment: I had scrolling problems when placing this code in `viewWillAppear`, and later attempting to call `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. The table view would refuse to scroll, even though there were cells cut off. I was able to resolve this by placing the code in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Comment: In `viewWillAppear` in iOS 7, `self.view` still hasn't been resized if `self.parentViewController` is a `UINavigationController`. So, I came up with this [solution: `UITableView` scroll to bottom after load](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19367073/242933).

Comment: Was searching for this and found this. Works great in my chat app. +1

Comment: Please add some Swift :)

Answer (score 14):

Answer of @DyingCactus in **Swift 3** & **Swift 4**:

```
    let lastRow: Int = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) - 1
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow, section: 0);
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: false)
```

Comment: this causing jumping. When the VC finally appears on screen only then the table view scrolls. I am calling it from `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 9):

You can call -scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated within the -viewWillAppear: method of your TableViewController.

atScrollPosition: allows you to set where you want your cell for rowAtIndexPath to appear. There are four options:

**UITableViewScrollPositionTop**
- puts your cell right at the top of the view

**UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle**
- centers your cell in the view

**UITableViewScrollPositionBottom**
- puts your cell at the bottom

**UITableViewScrollPositionNone** 
- Using this setting will position in the cell in user view with minimum scrolling/movement.

The behavior is different in three scenarios :-

If the cell is already in view, it does nothing.

If the cell is above the current view, it scrolls the cell to the top of the view.

If the cell is beneath  the current view, it scrolls the cell to the bottom of the view.

Comment: How we can scroll to a non visible cell ?

Answer (score 7):

I'm using autolayout and none of the answers worked for me. Here is my solution that finally  worked:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL shouldScrollToLastRow;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _shouldScrollToLastRow = YES;
}


- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Scroll table view to the last row
    if (_shouldScrollToLastRow)
    {
        _shouldScrollToLastRow = NO;
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    }
}
```

Comment: This caused my tableview to scroll to far, so I used `[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.frame.size.height)];`, and to use it after the view has been loaded you need to make sure all cells are drawn, like `[self performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: `

Comment: Worked for me by replacing CGFLOAT_MAX with the calculated height. Also got rid of the annoying visual jumping with no animations that was visible with all the other solutions I'd tried.

Answer (score 6):

Following DyingCactus's reply above, I added this method to my controller:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
      [self.tableView reloadData];    
      NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1 inSection:0];
      [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

And now it works, exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: The line where you set the NSIndexPath doesn't look right.  I will edit my answer with what I think it should be.

Comment: Edited to reflect the fix. Silly of me not to have realized that I was passing `mumberOfRowsInSection` rather than the index. Thanks again!

Comment: Great.  You may also want to add in a check for zero rows and not call the scroll in that case unless your tableview will always have at least one row.

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing this morning in the shower. Will do.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with scrollToRowAtIndexPath method is its slow and the tableView takes time to scroll to the bottom.

i had the exact same problem, after trying everything(same as you), this worked, the key is if you're using autolayout 
initialize scrollToBottom to true and then do this

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    // Scroll table view to the last row
    [self scrollToBottom];
}

-(void)scrollToBottom {
    if (shouldScrollToLastRow)
    {
        CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height);
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
    } }
```

doing this will ensure you're almost at the bottom of you're tableView but might not be at the very bottom as its impossible to know the exact bottom offset when you're at the top of the tableView, so after that we can implement scrollViewDidScroll

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
    float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
    float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
    float scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    // if you're not at bottom then scroll to bottom
    if (!(scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight))
    {
        [self scrollToBottom];
    } else {
    // bottom reached now stop scrolling
        shouldScrollToLastRow = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController
CGFloat labelWidth = 260.0f;
CGFloat labelRequiredHeight = 180.0f;
@synthesize tblView;
@synthesize txtField;
@synthesize chatData;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tblView.delegate = self;

    [self.tblView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    chatData  = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self registerForKeyboardNotifications];

}

-(IBAction) textFieldDoneEditing : (id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"the text content%@",txtField.text);
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [txtField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)sendButton:(id)sender
{
    if (txtField.text.length>0) {
        // updating the table immediately
        NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"text"];
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:txtField.text];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:data];
        [chatData addObject:dictionary];

        NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
        [tblView beginUpdates];
        [tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tblView endUpdates];
        [tblView reloadData];

        txtField.text = @"";
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
}

-(IBAction) backgroundTap:(id) sender
{
    [self.txtField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)SendbtnShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield
{
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog(@"the text content%@",txtField.text);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    if (txtField.text.length>0)
    {
        // updating the table immediately
        NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"text"];
        NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObject:txtField.text];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        [chatData addObject:dictionary];

        NSMutableArray *insertIndexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSIndexPath *newPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [insertIndexPaths addObject:newPath];
        [tblView beginUpdates];
        [tblView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [tblView endUpdates];
        [tblView reloadData];
        txtField.text = @"";
    }
    return NO;
}


// Keyboard Functionality

-(void) registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) freeKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

-(void) keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard was shown");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    // Get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    // Move
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    NSLog(@"frame..%f..%f..%f..%f",self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"keyboard..%f..%f..%f..%f",keyboardFrame.origin.x, keyboardFrame.origin.y, keyboardFrame.size.width, keyboardFrame.size.height);
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y- keyboardFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+ keyboardFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardFrame.size.height)];
    [tblView scrollsToTop];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

-(void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSLog(@"Keyboard will hide");
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    // Get animation info from userInfo
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
    CGRect keyboardFrame;
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
    [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardFrame];
    // Move
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y + keyboardFrame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [tblView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tblView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tblView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    self.tblView.scrollEnabled=chatData;


}

#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource protocol methods
- (void)scrollTableToBottom
{
    int rowNumber = [self.tblView numberOfRowsInSection:1];
    if (rowNumber > 0) [self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [chatData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"chatCell";
    chatCell *cell = (chatCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @"chatCellIdentifier"];
    if(!cell)
        cell =[[chatCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
//    NSUInteger row = [chatData count]-[indexPath row]-1;
    NSUInteger row=[indexPath row];
    NSUInteger count = [chatData count];
    if (row <chatData.count)
    {
        NSString *chatText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"text"];
        cell.txtMsg.text = chatText;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellText = [[chatData objectAtIndex:chatData.count-indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"text"];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(225.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        return labelSize.height + 40;
}


//-(void)scrollToBottomTableView
//{
//    if (self.tblView.contentOffset.y > self.tblView.frame.size.height)
//    {
//        [self.tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self. indexPathForLastMessage]
//                              atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
//    }
//}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

//        [tblView reloadData];
//   
//    int lastRowNumber = [tblView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
//    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
//    [tblView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
//[tblView reloadData];

}
- (void)reloadTableViewDataSource
{
    [tblView reloadData];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: my code doesnot add text from the last cell of the table....like chating app...plz help me

Comment: You should also describe what your code is doing or why.

Comment: my code add the text from the top of table and not scroll at the last row of the table.

Comment: when i use view willAppear method my app is crashes.

Answer (score -1):

Note for scrolling to the bottom row, the section needs to be last section not 0 (first section):

```
int lastSection = [self.myTableView numberOfSections] -1;
if (lastSection < 0) return;

int lastRow = [self.myTableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSection] - 1;
if (lastRow < 0) return;  
NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:lastSection];

 [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: func scrollToBot() {
        let lastSection = self.numberOfSections - 1
        guard lastSection >= 0 else { return }
        let lastRow = self.numberOfRowsInSection(lastSection) - 1
        guard lastRow >= 0 else { return }
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:lastRow, inSection: lastSection)
        self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated:false)
    }