# Issue with UICollectionView Content size Height

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I am using `UICollectionView`
After reloading the collectionView data, I am not getting the exact content size height of the collection view. It always return the previous content size height of the collection view after updating the next view.
I also using `CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout` for `collectionViewLayout`.

My code is look like that

```
- (void)loadCollectionView {
   [_collectionView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"contentSize%f",self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height);

}
```

Please help.

Comment: reloadData is not a synchronous call. Do you have to get the contentsize in loadCollectionView?

Comment: You can study this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163579/how-to-detect-the-end-of-loading-of-uitableview and change your code accordingly.

Comment: Yes 
lead_the_zeppelin, I need the Size of `UIcollectionView` after reloading all data in `UIcollectionView`.