# UITableview Scrolls to Top on Reload

Tags: swift, tableview, cell, reloaddata

I am facing problem in my app - you can post and edit your favorite places. After posting a post, or editing a specific post (`UITableViewCell`), `UITableview` is reloaded.

My problem is: the `UITableview` scrolls to the top after reloading. But that's not what I want. I want my view to stay on the cell / view where I was. But I don't know how to manage that.

Could you help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the UITableView method: reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043632/auto-scrolling-to-a-cell-with-a-specific-value   you might need to save the index you are looking at when you reload to know where to scroll to

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Igor's answer is correct if you are using dynamically resizable cells (UITableViewAutomaticDimension)

Here it is in swift 3:

```
    private var cellHeights: [IndexPath: CGFloat?] = [:]
    var expandedIndexPaths: [IndexPath] = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cellHeights[indexPath] = cell.frame.height
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if let height = cellHeights[indexPath] {
            return height ?? UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        }
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }


    func expandCell(cell: UITableViewCell) {
      if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
        if !expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
            expandedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)
            cellHeights[indexPath] = nil
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
            //tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: surprisingly this helped and I am not using dynamic cell heights. Thank you!

Comment: yeah this code is useful when you adding a dynamic row height using programatically. I was calculating row height from textview text. Small bump comes in when reloading tableview. Adding this code will remove that small bump.

Comment: Whats the purpose of expandCell() method, I couldn't understand it. Is it just for demonstration or i need to use it as well in my code?

Answer (score 16):

To prevent scrolling to top, you should save heights of cells when they loads and give exact value in `tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
// declare cellHeightsDictionary
NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary;

// initialize it in ViewDidLoad or other place
cellHeightsDictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;

// save height
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cellHeightsDictionary setObject:@(cell.frame.size.height) forKey:indexPath];
}

// give exact height value
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSNumber *height = [cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (height) return height.doubleValue;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Comment: this works, but can you explain why heightForRowAt is not enough?

Comment: This is working for the tableviews when doing for bottom scroll. But not working in case of top scroll. Can you give some suggestion what may be the issue exactly?

Comment: Do you mean a case when you scroll to some indexPath programmatically, skipping some first rows? If yes, then you can do pre-calculate heights.

Comment: Facing same issue as  @Gautam Shrivastav, When scroll to top and load new rows at top, it auto scrolls to top of new data, rather it should keep on the last visible cell.

Answer (score 10):

The `UITableView`'s `reloadData()` method is explicitly a force reload of the entire tableView. It works well, but is usually jarring and a bad user experience if you're going to do that with a tableview that the user is currently looking at.

Instead, take a look at `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(_:withRowAnimation:)` and 
`reloadSections(_:withRowAnimation:)` [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:).

Comment: Both of these methods trigger full reloads sometimes.

Answer (score 6):

Just go for these lines if you want an easy solution

```
let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

Answer (score -2):

In swift 3.1

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

    self.TableView.reloadData()
    self.TableView.contentOffset = .zero

})
```

Comment: @OsamaBinBashir not really, but you have to call this methods on the main thread.

Comment: @EduardoIrias agree on that :)

Answer (score -4):

Now with swift 5 we can do that with a simple `tableview.reloadDataAndKeepOffset()`

Comment: There is no such a thing as `reloadDataAndKeepOffset()`.