# Scrolling to a tableview row which is not loaded yet

Tags: swift, uitableview

Is it possible to scroll to a particular uitableview row using scrollToRow(at: , at: , animated:) if that uitableview row is not loaded yet. If yes then how can I achieve this. If no then is there any workaround.

Comment: You can scrollToRow(at: , at: , animated:) after loaded only.

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043632/auto-scrolling-to-a-cell-with-a-specific-value

Comment: Actually I know which row to scroll to but that row is not loaded yet

Comment: You can also use setContentOffest if you know all rows heights, then you can calculate desired row y position

Comment: You can scroll to any IndexPath but point to remember is that its row index should not be more than size of array otherwise you will get exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after table data loaded, call tableView.scrollToRow(at:, at: , animated:) and reload the table view