# How to run code after uitableview has loaded a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to run code which relies on the table view and all its cell's being loaded. The code needs to be run on the cells, but after they're initialised completely, not in cellForRowAtIndexPath (they need to have been drawn already because I'm using autolayout and need to run this code after it)

How can I know when they're loaded?

EDIT - 
i think theres some confusion

Basically every time i add a cell, cellForRowAtIndexPath creates this cell. It is not yet rendered. After this method, the cell is rendered. After render, i want to run some code

Comment: what you want to achieve ? because `cellforrow` getcalled everytime when you scroll also. So cell will be resue continously!!

Comment: You can try to put that code in layoutSubviews in your custom cell

Comment: _After this method means_ this method: `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` ??

Comment: @Mr.UB yes it does

Comment: What about tableView willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: delegate method?

Comment: @MaticOblak that is called before drawing "Tells the delegate the table view is about to draw a cell for a particular row."

Comment: Then you can ping visible cells on scrollview did scroll

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect the end of loading of UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163579/how-to-detect-the-end-of-loading-of-uitableview)

Comment: @pedrouan that is asking for after table load, im asking for after each cell loads

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked. This runs after every cell has been drawn

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    for i in 0...3{
        let cell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
        //do what i needed
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This does not run after a cell is added, only works on cells which were there when the original table was loaded. What works better is putting this same method in the UITableViewCell class. That way it runs after each cell has been rendered:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let cell = self
        //do what i needed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method UITableView Delegate in your case:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
//Your required code will be here.
```

}

This method will call when cell is rendered and you are viewing it.

Comment: This is Objective-C code, not Swift. And it has syntax errors

Comment: No. This detects when a cell has been removed

Comment: @HamzahMalik The previous delegate called when cell ends displaying on screen and you are not viewing it like if you scroll it up or down.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        for index in 0 ..< cell_Total_Count {
            if let cell = TableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? UITableViewCell_FileName {
               //Do cell stuff here...
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: You can use viewWillLayoutSubviews() method because it gets called after rendering cell.

Comment: Answer should be always with some explanation, only code will be treated as **Low Quality Answer**.

Comment: Although your code snippet might solve the issue, you should describe what’s the purpose of your code (how it solves the problem). Furthermore, you might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.