# Un-scrollable table views inside scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have used a UIScroll View. It has a contentView (of type UIView) which again has a questionView (UIView) and 2 table views (UITableView). I want questionView and table views to scroll together so I disabled scrolling of table views hoping that scrollView will handle the scrolling. But its not happening. I suspect that the issue is with non-scrollable table views because of which Scroll view is not able to identify the right height of its contentView and hence, not scrolling. For enabling scroll, I added:

```
self.questionTableView.scrollEnabled = self.answerTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

I read couple of questions on stack overflow but none of them fit my requirement.

[image]

Comment: Please tell the reason of down-voting. I will improve on that

Comment: your question is too broad. What is the issue ? Is your scrollview not scrolling ?  Why do you have a tableView in a scroll View ? The easisest way would be use one tableView and play with the sections.

Comment: O so i can have a 1 main table view with 2 sections. first section for the question view and the next section to accommodate questionTableView and answerTableView (the last 2 table views are adjacent to each other).

Comment: yes. You can control every section/row attributes in the tableView!

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set scroll view content size after table load

```
float sizeOfContent = 0;
 NSInteger questionTblHight = self.questionTableView.contentSize.height;
 NSInteger answerTbHight = self.answerTableView.contentSize.height;

sizeOfContent = questionTblHight+answerTbHight;

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```

Comment: I tried changing content size according to table's height but didn't work.

Comment: make sure some point  1.set content size after table data load 2. Add UIScrollViewDelegate

Comment: Thanks! It works!! As of now I am setting content size after each cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is there any native method to identify if all the cells have reloaded? I dont want to use NSTimer and all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163579/how-to-detect-the-end-of-loading-of-uitableview this link help you

Comment: Thanks for the link. The cells which are visible in the first screen are tappable but after scrolling down, even though i can see the cells but they are not tappable. I tried _scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES; as well but no luck

Comment: i think you should to use _scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;