# Setting UITableView datasource programmatically makes it reload table asynchronously

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to call `tableView.reloadData()` and be sure that after that table rows are rendered.
The problem is that not happening when I am setting datasource programmatically before that. Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
        print("after reloadData")
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAt")
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Output is:

1. print("after reloadData")
2. print("cellForRowAt")

I expect it to print “cellForRowAt” first. Why is that happening?

Update:
It's silly but I thought `reloadData()` was synchronous.
What did the trick for me is:
`self.tableView.layoutIfNeezded()`
Thank you and thx [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366713/2528850).

Comment: You are reloading the table before it is on screen, so it doesn't need to perform a rendering pass. Once the tableview is visible (After `viewDidLayoutSubviews`) it will need cells

Comment: Well actually the call to the method tableView.reloadData() is asynchronous . Or more acurately methods like numberOfRows ,heightForRow gets calledUp first ,but CellForRowAtIndexPath doesnot. This is the reason why you see this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `tableView.reloadData()` is asynchronous it contains a patch of calls to dataSource methods in order until that happens you see the print first