# UITableView , Scroll to bottom on reload?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITableView` with `cells` that are dynamically updated. Everything works fine apart from when `tableview.reload` is called (see below) to refresh the `cells` in the table I would like the table to scroll to the bottom to show the new entries.

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"RELOAD TABLE ...");
    [customTableView reloadData];
    // Scroll to bottom of UITable here ....
}
```

I was planning to use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` but then noticed that I don't have access to an `indexPath`.

Does anyone know how to do this, or of a `delegate` callback that I could use?

Comment: Similar to [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156614/how-to-start-uitableview-on-the-last-cell). Apparently, the trick there was to call `numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use:

```
NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: cells_count-1 inSection: sections_count-1];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES];
```

Or you can specify the section index manually (If one section => index=0).

Comment: I don't think [customTableView reloadData] is a blocking call. If that code is copy-pasted right after the reloadData it will generate an exception since there is no real data at that moment. I will test this.

Comment: No it won't crash - reloadData is synchronous

Comment: To scroll to the bottom use UITableViewScrollPositionBottom

Comment: @Max Why not use setContentOffset ?

Comment: Bad stuff happens if `cells_count` is 0

Comment: Note that this method may not work when you have set estimatedRowHeight to non-zero value. You need to disable estimatedRowHeight to get it works.

Answer (score 41):

Another solution is to flip the table vertically, and flip each cell vertically:

Apply the transform to the UITableView when initializing:

```
tableview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);
```

This way you don't need workarounds for scrolling issues, but you will need to think a little harder about contentInsets/contentOffsets and header/footer interactions.

Comment: This is hacky, but its so much more visually appealing than the other solutions!

Comment: You are genius! best way to do this. So elegant.

Comment: I hate to say it but this hack works better then all other methods.

Comment: SlackViewController uses this technique :)

Comment: @michael-wilson please please please tell us why this even works.

Comment: This is indeed a brilliant solution! It's not that difficult to see why this works. @GeorgeMaisuradze the first transform flips the whole tableview up-side down. So all cells are actually unreadable since it's up-side down. But without the cell transform you can already see that since the tableview is upside-down any pull-to-refresh would be at the bottom and you can use scrollToTop to easily scroll to the bottom: [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:animated];
Then simply use the flip-transform on the cells again to make them readable. Brilliant!

Comment: Awesome . Just FYI. You'll need to swap your header with footer and flip the views too ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, footer is showing on the top :(.which is basically a big empty space.

Comment: Wow, I spent 2 days trying to create smooth scrolling and loading previous data when the scroll approaches top. Finally found this post and this solution totally changed my approach. Now everything works so smooth that I would give 100 pluses to you Mr. Michael Wilson. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

```
-(void)scrollToBottom{

        [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.height) animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: This seems to be a better solution for a general case of scrolling to the bottom. If the contents of your tableview change, or you've deallocated the table when you attempt to scroll, cells_count will probably be 0 and you may run into some issues. Scrolling to the end of the table by it's size may be slightly more robust. I'll be using this moving forward. Admittedly, the question doesn't require this.

Answer (score 10):

```
//In swift 

var iPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0)-1, 
                        inSection: self.tableView.numberOfSections()-1)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(iPath, 
                                      atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Bottom,                     
                                      animated: true)
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

For all the folks here trying to figure out how to solve this problem the key is to call the `.layoutIfNeeded()` method after `.reloadData()` :

```
tableView.reloadData()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.height), animated: false)
```

I was working with multiple sections in `UITableView` and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you. It is the most valuable answer for the case when autolayout is used. There are plenty of possibilities to perform scroll and calculate offset, but they are of no help because layout is not updated yet, when setContentOffset called. And call .layoutIfNeeded() resolves this problem.

Comment: This actually works if number of rows changes :) thanks

Answer (score 8):

Fot Swift 5

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        let section = self.numberOfSections
        if section > 0 {
            let row = self.numberOfRows(inSection: section - 1)
            if row > 0 {

                self.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: row-1, section: section-1), at: .bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As this is something you might want to use really often, I suggest that you create a class extension on UITableView :

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToBottom(animated: Bool = true) {
        let section = self.numberOfSections
        if section > 0 {
            let row = self.numberOfRowsInSection(section - 1)
            if row > 0 {
                self.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: row - 1, inSection: section - 1), atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: animated)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is another solution, worked well in my case, when cell height is big.

```
- (void)scrollToBottom
{
    CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, _bubbleTable.contentSize.height - _bubbleTable.bounds.size.height);
    if ( bottomOffset.y > 0 ) {
        [_bubbleTable setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

extension is better to be done on UIScrollView instead of UITableView, this way it works on scrollView, tableView, collectionView (vertical), UIWebView (inner scroll view), etc

```
public extension UIScrollView {

    public func scrollToBottom(animated animated: Bool) {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, contentSize.height - bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height)
        scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: animated)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5

```swift
    func scrollToBottom() {
        let section = self.tableView.numberOfSections
        let row = self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: self.tableView.numberOfSections - 1) - 1;
        guard (section > 0) && (row > 0) else{ // check bounds
            return
        }
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row-1, section: section-1)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

I dont agree that we should user `cells_count`,`sections_count`,`self.dateSource.count`and so on, Instead, the delegate will be better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way.

```
- (void)scrollToBottom
{
    CGFloat yOffset = 0;

    if (self.tableView.contentSize.height > self.tableView.bounds.size.height) {
        yOffset = self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height;
    }

    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, yOffset) animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code, It may help you:

```
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+0.1, execute: {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.dateSource.count-1, section: 0)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    })
```