# is it possible to get a callback when a UITableView reload is done?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, animation, scroll

I am reloading some cells in my table view.  After the reload is done, I want to scroll so that they are visible.  I am aware of the scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition: method.  But I need to call it after the reload as done, as said reload will change row heights.

Here are some related questions, but they don't quite answer my question.
[UITableView , Scroll to bottom on reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112346/uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-on-reload)
[How to Start UITableView on the Last Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156614/how-to-start-uitableview-on-the-last-cell)

EDIT -- My reload does not insert or delete any rows.  Rather, I am reloading one or more cells to reflect updated information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112346/uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-on-reload

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071503/how-to-tell-when-uitableview-has-completed-reloaddata

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hacky ways you could do it:

1) When you call reloadData, your cellForRowAtIndexPath: delegate function will get called once for every visible cell. You could count those and then trigger an action after the function has been called enough times.

2) I bet some of the other UITableViewDelegate functions also get called in a deterministic way. Maybe you can just call your refresh function in one of those, perhaps with a small delay.

3) You could also use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: after [tableView reloadData] and use some hard-coded delay.

Answer (score -3):

Not an ideal solution but I have gotten around this using a UIView animation and corresponding completion callback. I place this in a UITableView category. Works as you'd expect.

```
- (void)reloadDataWithCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.33 animations:^(){
    [self reloadData];
  }completion:completion];
}
```