# Tableview pulldown to refresh

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Ha ii everybody,i am familiar with pullDownToRefresh in tableview but in want pulluptorefresh in my application like the pocket-sword bible application chapter loading pull-up for next-chapter and pulldown for previous chapter,i done the ordinary pulldown method,but i want pull-up,i tried to customize the existing pulldown code but no luck,i tried more than 4 days for this. i want to implement pull-up below the footer just like the pulldown just-above the header.
anyone have any idea about this please help me.
Kind regards Nipin.

```
- (void)addPullToRefreshHeader {
    refreshHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0 - REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    refreshHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    refreshLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)];
    refreshLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    refreshLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
    refreshLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    refreshLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    refreshArrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    refreshArrow.frame = CGRectMake((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 27) / 2,
                                    (REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 44) / 2,
                                    27, 44);

    refreshSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    refreshSpinner.frame = CGRectMake((REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2, (REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT - 20) / 2, 20, 20);
    refreshSpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshLabel];
    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshArrow];
    [refreshHeaderView addSubview:refreshSpinner];
    [self.table addSubview:refreshHeaderView];
}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (isLoading) return;
    isDragging = YES;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (isLoading) {
        // Update the content inset, good for section headers
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0)
            self.table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT)
            self.table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (isDragging && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        // Update the arrow direction and label
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
            // User is scrolling above the header
            refreshLabel.text = @"Release to previous chapter...";
            [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
        } else { // User is scrolling somewhere within the header
            refreshLabel.text = @"Pull down to previous chapter..";
            [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (isLoading) return;
    isDragging = NO;
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= -REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT) {
        // Released above the header
        [self startLoading];
    }
}

- (void)startLoading {
    isLoading = YES;
    delegate.selectedChapter = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[delegate.selectedChapter intValue] + 1];
    [delegate reloadVerses];
    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
    // Show the header
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    self.table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(REFRESH_HEADER_HEIGHT, 0, 0, 0);
    refreshLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    refreshArrow.hidden = YES;
    [refreshSpinner startAnimating];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // Refresh action!
    [self refresh];
}

- (void)stopLoading {
    isLoading = NO;

    // Hide the header
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(stopLoadingComplete:finished:context:)];
    self.table.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    [refreshArrow layer].transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI * 2, 0, 0, 1);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)stopLoadingComplete:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    // Reset the header
    refreshLabel.text =@"Pull down to previous chapter..";
    refreshArrow.hidden = NO;
    [refreshSpinner stopAnimating];
}

- (void)refresh {
    // This is just a demo. Override this method with your custom reload action.
    // Don't forget to call stopLoading at the end.
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopLoading) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly about your task. But try out following code which identifies the scrollPosition of `UITableView` :

```
NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: cells_count-1 inSection: sections_count-1];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated: YES]
```

For more reference go to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112346/uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-on-reload)

Comment: sir ,please seee my edit in my question.how can i add your code in my app?