# Load more to last position in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I try to Build UITableView That load every time a 5 object and when I notice that the scroll table in the last position I reload table data and this open the table from the top again.

how I can save the position and when table reload back to last cell I see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code before you reload the table data

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:(numberOfRowsInLastSection - 1) inSection:(numberOfSections - 1)];
```

By the above line you will get the position of last row of table.

Use this code after reloading the tableView

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

This will scroll to already saved position.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution in this post - [UITableView , Scroll to bottom on reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112346/uitableview-scroll-to-bottom-on-reload)

```
[postTableView reloadData];

 NSIndexPath* ipath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: oldSkip -1 inSection: 1];
[postTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: ipath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Same logic posted. Why don't give +1 and mark answer as correct

Comment: now you have a mark as correct answer and like from me  (-: