# scrollToRowAtIndexPath doesn't handle the last row properly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, user-interface

I'm having an issue with `UITableView` where it doesn't seem to handle scrolling to the last row properly when using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated`

Here's the code I'm using to cause the scroll:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                              animated:YES];
```

And here's a screenshot showing the result (*and the issue!*):

[image: UITableView scroll issue screenshot]

As you can see, the very last row (*September*) isn't scrolled fully into view; the bottom few pixels are cut-off.

I've tried using `UITableViewScrollPositionNone`, `UITableViewScrollPositionTop` and `UITableViewScrollPositionBottom` as the scroll position but they all produce the same result.

My cell does have a custom cell height of `61.0f` which is currently set in the storyboard, but adding the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and returning the same value doesn't help either.

Is there any way I can get the table view to scroll to the last row **AND** have it fully visible?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I'm using a stock `UINavigationController` with a stock `UITableViewController` as it's root view controller.

**EDIT 2:**

If I use `rectForRowAtIndexPath:` to determine the rect for the row, it does in-fact return the correct rect for that row. But if I then call `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` using that rect, I get the same result as above; the bottom few pixels are cut-off.

Comment: What's your table view's frame, what are its content insets?

Comment: I'll check. But like I said, I aren't manipulating those; I've just dragged a UITableViewController from the palette onto the canvas in IB.

Comment: Are you able to manually scroll to the last cell and see it in it's entirety?

Comment: @mharper I certainly am. Also, if I flick the table view so it scrolls to the very bottom, when it's done bouncing and comes to a stop, the last row is fully in view.

Comment: When are you scrolling to the bottom? You're sure you're scrolling to the last row? Please show some code.

Comment: It's called from viewWillAppear and a private method which is triggered when the underlying data source changes.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout? If so, have you pinned the table view to the bottom of it's super view?

Comment: I am using AutoLayout. I haven't touched the layout of the table view since it's a stock UITableViewController added from the palette in IB. I've not added the table view manually.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Okay, I've successfully been able to fix this issue.

The clue was in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156614/how-to-start-uitableview-on-the-last-cell#comment28699924_2156877) by [Matt Di Pasquale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242933/mattdipasquale) on a semi-related question.

It turns out that in iOS 7, the views are yet to be laid out when `viewWillAppear:` is called, meaning the frame and bounds of the table view are not guaranteed to be accurate. Since the call to `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:animated` must use at least one of these to calculate the offset, this makes sense as to why in my case it wasn't being handled properly.

I think in most cases people won't encounter this issue as their presenting view controller will likely have the same bounds as the presented view controller. But in my case, I was presenting a view controller that had a visible navigation bar and status bar from one that didn't have either, ergo there was an extra 64pts to account for. As can be seen in this console output:

```
2014-03-15 19:14:32.129 Capture[3375:60b] viewWillAppear, tv bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
2014-03-15 19:14:32.131 Capture[3375:60b] viewDidLayoutSubviews, tv bounds: {{0, -64}, {320, 568}}
```

To get around the issue, I now set a flag in `viewWillAppear:` that signifies there's a pending scroll and then in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, if the flag is set, I call `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:animated` and unset the flag (*since this method is called numerous times*). This works flawlessly.

Hopefully this will help anyone else coming across the issue.

Comment: I was forced to use manual offset calculations since iOS7 is out until today I see this!!  Wish I had read this post earlier!  Thanks!

Comment: Nice suggestion but does not work for me.  I am loading the data in a separate thread.  Once the data is loaded I call `[mytableView reload]`.  And that does make a call to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Still fishing for an solution - do not want to manually adjust.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a lower-level function? After all, a `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`.

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height} animated:YES];
```

(Adjust the offset as desired if you have content edge insets other than 0).

Comment: Worked for me, but had to adjust to `[self.tableView setContentOffset:(CGPoint){0, self.tableView.contentSize.height} animated:YES];`

Comment: could you explain what you mean by low-level function? are you saying the standard scrollToRow not reliable?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same bug when I was scrolling to the particular row of the `tableView` when user touches back button. I noticed that `contentInset` of the table view is changing during the navigation (due to `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true`). The only solution I found is to add an observer:

```
tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentInset", options: .new, context: nil)
```

and perform the `scrollToRow` method **after** the `contentInset` establishes. This is not a beautiful solution, but it works.

Answer (score -1):

I would also suggest you turn of a `UIViewController` property, which is on by default:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets;
```

This one has helped me with many issues, when I did not know why `UITableView` (which is a subclass of `UIScrollView` actually) was not scrolling properly. Depending on your layout of course.

This property is available since iOS 7, read more about it here:

http://b2cloud.com.au/general-thoughts/uiviewcontroller-changes-in-ios7

Comment: This property was added because on iOS 7 the views automatically extend under the navigation and toolbars, and that's behaviour I want. The scroll methods should take this into account in their internal implementation.

Comment: I do not think this property affect that as much. In my case it only moved the scrollView inset for 20pt, which is the size of Status bar, not navigation or toolbar.

Comment: Deprecated since iOS 11, is now likely `scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .automatic` if yes before

Comment: Actually, it did not help me either.